# Docusign API limits and violations

Tags: docusignapi

I want to make the below three calls one by one immediately  from my app. All are get calls to Docusign and all are  different urls but same envelope id .

Is it possible to do make below three calls immediately from my app or we need to make call after 15 minutes.. for go live?

Calls:

```
baseUrl + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId+ "/documents/combined";

baseUrl+"/envelopes/"+envelopeId+"/recipients/1/tabs";

baseUrl + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/documents/certificate";
```

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for Go Live are insane. I was NOT able to pass using my application. Its really annoying because after you fail you have to wait 24 hours or generate a new api key and redo all the testing.

I eventually was able to pass it by creating 20 compliant requests in postman. As far as I can tell, once in production the 15 min unique resource restriction is not enforced.

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules)

> You may not exceed 1 GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes.

---

You can make the first two calls within the 15 minute window as they are invoking **unique** endpoints.

However you cannot repeat the call to the same endPoint within the 15 minute window for the same envelope.

**API Limit Violations:**

- *Example*: Calling the [GetDocument](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) Api within 5 minutes.

Calls

```
11:00 AM 
GET baseUrl + "/envelopes/F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4/documents/combined"

11:05AM 
GET baseUrl + "/envelopes/F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4/documents/combined"
```

Comment: Actually I believe all three ok, the rules are slightly ambiguous but they are still unique endpoints, with the first ending with `/combined` and the second with `/certificate`.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to [API Rule #2](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules) which states

> You may not exceed 1 GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes.

The 3 requests should be fine, even though it's the same envelope it is still unique (different) endpoints.  Even when you get the documents for instance, the first request is made against the `.../combined` endpoint whereas the third is made against `.../certificate` endpoint.

The good thing here is that you can now validate your transactions in self-service fashion using the automated [API Go Live](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-go-live-process-now-automated/) process.  Note that this is only accessible through developer sandbox accounts, not live production accounts.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I completed 32(above urls  4 * 8) calls/transaction.Review was failed.Can i know the reason for this?

Comment: @Ergin I have a question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197220/docusign-api-limits-one-get-request-per-unique-envelope-endpoint-per-15-minutes