# Docusign API Limits: one GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes

Tags: docusignapi

Regarding Docusign's API [one GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes limit](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/resource_limits.html): if we do a POST on the unique envelope endpoint are we OK to follow up with another GET to the same unique envelope endpoint within 15 minutes? In other words, **does a POST reset the GET limit counter**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Docusign enforces the 15 minute rule per unique envelope endpoint is to prevent callers from repeatedly polling for the same envelope status. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941048/1219543).

Q :*Does a POST reset the GET limit counter?*

> A POST call will NOT reset the GET limits.

In the following example,  even though a POST call is made, the last call will violate the 15 minute rule.  A GET call for envelope `AAA` is made twice within 15 minutes.

```
[12:01:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA 
[12:02:00] POST /accounts/12345/envelopes
[12:03:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/BBB
[12:04:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA * (Violation)
```

The following is **NOT** an API violation because you are accessing unique envelope end points.

```
[12:00:00] POST /accounts/12345/envelopes
[12:01:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1
[12:02:00] GET  /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/recipients/2
```